# Tkinter text window writing with irremovable line space

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I'm busy using tkinter in my python program, and I'm busy reading and then inserting into a text window, but there appears to be a line spacing between my input which shouldn't be there.

See following read to insert code:

```
def writer(self, Tk, textobject, n):
    for line in textobject:
            textwindow.insert(Tk.INSERT, line + "\n")
            self.sleeper(n)
```

See output:

> TEXT LINE 1
>
> TEXT LINE 2

EDIT: See what output should be:

> TEXT LINE 1 
>  TEXT LINE 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using

```
textwindow.insert(Tk.INSERT, line + "\n")
```

There is no need to use

```
"\n"
```

As inserting a line creates its own new line already. 
As such, I removed the "\n" and found that it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to read TEXT LINE 1 TEXT LINE 2,  remove the "\n".

Your code will look like:

```
def writer(self, Tk, textobject, n):
    for line in textobject:
            textwindow.insert(Tk.INSERT, line)
            self.sleeper(n)
```

Comment: See edit, I need to remove the line spacing between the text lines.

Comment: see answer below, removing the "\n" will not keep it on the same line.